# Why this HashMap.get return a null?

Tags: java

I am inserting the values into `HashMap` like this

```
String group_name[]=group_names.split(",");
String group_ids[]=new_groups.split(",");
Hashtable<Integer,String> hm=new Hashtable<Integer,String>(10);
for(int i=0;i<group_ids.length;i++){
    if (group_ids[i]!=null && !group_ids.equals("")) {
        hm.put(Integer.parseInt(group_ids[i]), group_name[i]);
    }
```

in the below code list2 is `ArrayList` and it is having the keys of `HashMap` and i am retrieving the values like the following

```
for(String group_id1:list2) {
    int gid=Integer.parseInt(group_id1); 
    String group_name=hm.get(Integer.parseInt(group_id1));
```

here hm.get() method is  returning null

Comment: IMHO, You should use HashMap unless you have to use Hastable.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (group_ids[i]!=null && !group_ids.equals("")) {
```

should probably be

```
if (group_ids[i]!=null && !group_ids[i].equals("")) {
```

Comment: it is array so that's way i  am doing like that.i am checking for every string

Comment: @raju `group_ids.equals("")` will _always_ be false, because you're comparing objects of two different classes - `String[]` on the left and `String` on the right.

Comment: you can also use isEmpty() in java String instead of comparing with an empty string. like `group_ids[i].isEmpty()`

Comment: "i am checking for every string" but you are only work on one value at a time time. Do you want this to be false for every string just because one is a ""?

Comment: i changed it as u said.but again it is returning null

Comment: i have checked that is all the key-value are inserted or not but all the key-value pairs are inserted

Comment: @raju this may sound like an obvious question but are you definitely sure that all the entries in `list2` really correspond to entries in `hm`?

Comment: all are  correspond to HashMap and i observed by printing them.and also i did debugging.